# Is there a way to install dependencies as a program encounters them?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, binary

Recently had a couple of binary programs that came zipped archive (not as a Debian package), but still had dependencies in them (namely dwarf fortress and epsxe) and it feels a chore to go through the missing libraries one by one, checking what package it belongs to and installing that package.

Is there a way of combining programs like `ldd`, `apt-file` and `apt-get` to automatically install dependencies for that specific binary file?

Comment: Like I said in the original post, the programs came zipped, not in .deb format.

Comment: We may end up writing a script for this. I'm not aware of any tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after learning how to script bash I came up with this. Works for 64 and 32 bit dependencies.

```
#!/bin/bash
DESTINATION=${1/ /\\ }
TYPE=$(eval readelf -h $DESTINATION | grep Class | awk ' {print $2}')
FILES=$(eval ldd $DESTINATION | grep "not found" | awk ' {print $1} ' | paste -s -d ' ')
for FILE in $FILES; do
  PACKAGE=$(apt-file search $FILE | awk ' {print $1}' | sed 's/://g' | uniq)
  if [ ! -z $PACKAGE ]
  then
    if [ $TYPE = "ELF32" ]
    then
      sudo apt install ${PACKAGE}:i386
    else
      sudo apt install ${PACKAGE}
    fi
  fi
done
```

https://github.com/Managor/install-deps.sh if I ever make changes.